# How to concatenate literal string and MACRO to valid string in c++

Tags: c++, string, qt, macros

I have :

```
QString ver ="";
QString ver += "-svn-"SVN_REVISION
```

which yields an error pointing me to ver:

```
error: missing terminating " character
    ver += "-svn-"SVN_REVISION;
```

SVN_REVISION is defined as 1.

How can I concatenate them to be a valid string?

Comment: To clarify, `SVN_REVISION` is a macro with the literal *number* `1` and not the string `"1"`?

Comment: You need to use the `#` stringify operator. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the preprocessor's stringify support as has been mentioned in the comments. Here's an example:

```
#define BASIC_STR(x) #x
#define STR(x) BASIC_STR(x)

QString ver ="";
QString ver += "-svn-" STR(SVN_VERSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QString ver = QString("-svn-%1").arg(SVN_REVISION);
```